# Por que incluir ficheiro html5.js

Tags: javascript, html5

Vejo que alguns sites incluem um arquivo chamado de html5.js, para qual finalidade eles incluem isso?

Algo como isso:

`<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> <![endif]-->`

Answer (score 2):

Essa instrução garante que apenas os browsers que são do IE8 para baixo ([fonte aqui](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)) carreguem este arquivo `.js`.

*Shim*, de acordo com o Google, é

> a washer or thin strip of material used to align parts, make them fit, or reduce wear.

A parte que importa é o *make them fit*, ou seja, "fazer encaixar". O HTMl5shim serve para que os browsers mais antigos entendam algumas tags novas do HTML5, que não existiam na época que eles foram implementados, como `<article>` e `<section>`. Leia mais sobre ele [aqui](https://github.com/afarkas/html5shiv).